# How can I inject and remove php code before a function call

Tags: php, regex, code-injection

I want to be able to inject some php code (a profiler code) before and after a specific function. 
The function and the file will be inserted manually in a form, but I want the injection and the removal to be automatically. I use a regular expression to locate the desired function call but I couldn't not find how to place the enabling code before and the disabling code after it.

Comment: The easiest way is to split your string on { brackets and insert string after first bracket and than join it :)

Comment: i don't know how to, but know the way you should follow :) you should search "aop (aspect oriented programming) with php" in google.

Answer (score 2):

#### Functions - runkit

You may use [php runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) to simply rewrite that function. Let's say you want replace function `foo()`, at first you need to rename that function with [`runkit_function_rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php):

```php
runkit_function_rename( 'foo', '_foo');
```

And than just simply redefine your function (with dynamic handling of arguments via [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)):

```php
function foo() {
  // Pre code
  $result = call_user_func_array( '_foo', func_get_args());
  // Post code
  return $result;
}
```

Once you're done, you may remove temporary function [`runkit_function_remove()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php):

```php
runkit_function_remove( 'foo');

// And set up old one back
runkit_function_rename( '_foo', 'foo');
```

If you really need to change code of your function (inline) and "pre callback" and "post callback" aren't enough I'm afraid I've got bad news about your application design.

#### Methods - simple wrapper

When you need to update methods (not functions) you can encapsulate whole object with simple wrapper taking advantage of php [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), you should probably implement all of them, but I'm going to show just [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), [`__set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set), [`__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [`__isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset).

```php
class Wrapper {
// The class that we are about to handle
protected $___data = null;

// Actually the only function that is directly related  to Wrapper class
public function __construct( $data){
    $this->___data = $data;
}

// By default just call real method
// You may add pre and post callbacks for every function
public function __call( $funcName, $args){
    return call_user_func_array( array( $this->___data, $funcName), $args);
}

// Propagate set to deeper level
public function __set( $key, $val){
    $result = ($this->___data->{$key} = $val);
    if( $result == $this->___data){
        return $this;
    }
    return $result;
}

// Propagate get to deeper level
public function __get( $key){
    $result = $this->___data->{$key};
    if( $result == $this->___data){
        return $this;
    }
    return $result;
}

// Handles isset
public function __isset( $key){
    return isset( $this->___data->{$key});
}

}
```

Once you have this, you may simply extend this class just to have special handling for one method (say class `Bar` method `foo()`):

```php
WrapperBar extends Wrapper {
    public function foo(){
         // Add magick
         return call_user_func_array( array( $this->___data, 'foo'), func_get_args());
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```php
 $bar = new Bar();
 $bar = new WrapperBar( $bar);
 $bar->foo( 'One', 'Two', '...');
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to inject some php code (a profiler code) before and after a specific function. The function and the file will be inserted manually in a form, but I want the injection and the removal to be automatically. I use a regular expression to locate the desired function call but I couldn't not find how to place the enabling code before and the disabling code after it.

The wrong question will yield the wrong answers, I guess. If you want to profile specific functions, use a profiler like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) instead of a profiler you write yourself. Code injection to perform profiling sounds like a terrible amount of work, although it is possible using runkit, as *Vyktor* suggested.

If you actually want to run your own code, I guess the easiest solution would be to do something like this:

```
<?php
$profiler = function( $function ) {
   // your profiling code here.
};

$profiler( 'yourfunction' );
yourfunction( );
$profiler( 'yourfunction' );
```

Then, when you're done with profiling the application, you can simply use an alternative function for `$profiler` that does nothing, which means it won't be intrusive.

```
$profiler = function( $function ) {
    return;
};
```

Still, this leaves profiling spread all over your application. I'd just use the existing tools.

Comment: @Vyktor I 'm actually going to use xhprof and I wanted to place the xhprof_enable before and the xhprof_disable after the function call, in order to profile the function.
This can be done manually, but I thought to create an admintool for making the profiling faster.

Comment: @x_maras then runkit should work for you, prefix real functions with `_` or `fooooooooooooooooooo_` or whatever you want and create dummy versions which will call `xhprof_enable(); $result = _foo(); xhprof_disable(); return $result();`

Comment: @x_maras Okay, but why do you need to insert the code "automatically"? Can't you just profile once, fix the function and be remove the profiling code again? Also, with XDebug/KCacheGrind it will give you a complete result of the application, not just a small segment which may or may not be useful.

Comment: Yes I can do the profiling as you say, actually I think that I am going to do it like this manually. However, I want to profile many functions not for debugging but for researching alternatives and I thought would be a nice idea for the rest of the developers as well to be able to profile fast and easy a function call if they want.

Comment: @Vyktor
I think Senad gave me short of an answer. 
From the point of knowing the file and the function I could simply search for them and replace them as text

    xhprof_enable(<param>); function_name(<param>); $result = xhprof_disable();

In remove I replace this text back to the original.

It's kind of unintelligent solution, but it will work, don't you think?
I will give it a try...

Comment: @x_maras I consider editing code in such a fashion really bad practice, but whatever works for you is good answer....

Comment: Hi @Vyktor, I tried it and it worked, but it makes a mess with the structure of the code so I think I won't continue in this way...